# What considerations should be taken into account when adding any fruit to any cake?

Tags: baking, fruit, cake

I have a pineapple-orange cake recipe that is very good, but is from a relative - I didn't develop it.  I am curious how to adjust a typical cake recipe or even a box cake mix so that I can add fruit (pineapple, peaches, cherries, apples, oranges, mango, etc...)?  Do I need to adjust the baking soda, oil, flour, sugar, etc...?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding fruit will change the ratio of dry to liquid, so it may require more flour. It would also add some sweetness, so you may want to reduce the sugar a tad. But citrus fruits in particular are acidic, which might affect the leavening. I suspect it would depend on the type of fruit and how it's prepared.

Comment: Is it against site policy for Chad to ask post the recipe so Martha can comment?

Comment: Thanks Martha.  It's good to know about possibly adjusting the leavening.

Comment: @Neil: nope. The policy is against recipe swapping/solicitation in the general form of "what are good recipes for ...?"

Comment: @hobodave: Thanks, just looking for clarification.

Comment: uhmm so i need to know how to add fruit like say if you put it in the bottom of the pan? You know just to make it moist on the bottom. Would that work???

Answer (score 1):

For something simple answering the box cake mix portion of the question, you might want to consider variations on the "dump cake."  Fruit, usually canned but sometimes fresh and sometimes mixed with gelatin, is placed under a box cake mix with melted butter or butter and water on top and baked.  This allows you to do a variety of fruit flavors with one cake.